# Fast way to add an array of paragraphs to Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

The test code below examines paragraphs in ActiveDocument and puts 'copies' of unique paragraphs at the bottom of the document, followed by their original spacing blank paragraphs. Paragraphs are manipulated in an array, and qualifying paragraphs are then added one by one to the bottom of that document. Is there a faster way of adding those paragraphs there? I am hoping there is a way to add the array directly without needing the loop. I think that it is possible to assign an array to a range in Excel (see [Rick Rothstein](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2007/is-there-a-fast-method-to-write-a-vba-array-into-a/0cb01fbb-2453-4fee-aadc-d854c35d24fd)), but I can't see how to do that in Word 2010.

```
Sub FullArray()
Dim StartTime                          'Start time
Dim p As Paragraph                     'is each initial paragraph object in ActiveDocument
Dim pDict As New Scripting.Dictionary  'Keys=plain text versions of each inital para
                                       'Items=signifiers of each key's (and para's)uniqueness or otherwise
Dim t As String                        'Plain text version of each p, being a key of pDict

Dim pArray(1000) As Variant            'Contains all initial paragraph objects
Dim c As Integer                       'c is ordinal number of each element of pArray
Dim dky As String                      'dky is whichever element of pArray is to be used as a key of pDict
Dim pc As Integer                      'running count of plain text paras in pDict
Dim lastdky As Integer                 'signifies whether previous key of pDict is unique
'faster when dimmed, option explicit

StartTime = Timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False     'Line 1 of Go to end of doc
ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Select  'Line 2 of Go to end of doc. Is there a Faster way?
Selection.Collapse

'ADD each para object to Array. Write its plain text to dictionary...
'...in order to determine uniqueness of each para.
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    t = p.Range.Text
    If Not pDict.Exists(t) Then
        pDict.Add Key:=t, Item:=1   '1 flag means 1st instance of a para, including blamk paras
    Else: pDict(t) = 2              '2 flag means a para which has duplicates
    End If

    pc = pc + 1                     'count plain text paras in pDict
    pArray(pc) = p                  'set element number pc of Array = current paragraph object
Next p


'PLACE copies of certain paras at the end of document...
'...being those content-containing paras which were initially unique....
'...and place after each such para any following contiguous blank paras
lastdky = 1                         '2/1 means PREVIOUS initial paragraph had/had not dupes.
For c = pc - 1 To 1 Step -1
    dky = pArray(c)
    If pDict(dky) = 1 And pArray(c) <> Chr(13) Then Selection.FormattedText = pArray(c) 'place para with content ('content paras') at end
    If pArray(c) = Chr(13) And lastdky = 1 Then Selection.FormattedText = pArray(c)     'place (only) blank paras following content paras at end
    If pDict(dky) = 2 Then lastdky = 2 Else: lastdky = 1
Next c

MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) & " seconds", vbInformation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please put `Option Explciit` at the beginning of the code module. This will force you to declare (`Dim`) all the variables you use. Do that, then use the [edit] link below your question to insert that code in place of what you've provided. It would help us to know exactly what data types all these cryptic variable names are supposed to be... ALSO, *why* would you be adding the paragraphs to an array? Why not put them at the end of the document, directly?

Comment: FINALLY, no, Word provides no way to assign an array of paragraphs (or any other kind of object) to a "target range" in a document. More efficient would probably be to assemble the content into a valid Word Open XML string (flat-file OPC format) then write that in one action to the document using the `InsertXML` method.

Comment: Thanks Cindy. I'll explore Word Open XML.